# Signing key cannot be found

Tags: java, jwt, microprofile

Using http://jwtenizr.sh/ to generate the jwt microprofile configuration. Adding the microprofile-config.properties file works perfectly with quarkus but when trying with openliberty I get the following errror:

CWWKS5523E: The MicroProfile JWT feature cannot authenticate the request because a valid JWT cannot be created from the token included in the request. CWWKS6029E: The JSON Web Token (JWT) cannot be validated because a signing key cannot be found. The configured signature algorithm [RS256] requires a key to validate the token.

My server.xml is as follow:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="${project.artifactId}">

   <featureManager>
      <feature>mpJwt-1.1</feature>
      <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>
      <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
      <feature>mpConfig-1.3</feature>
      <feature>mpOpenAPI-1.0</feature>
      <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
   </featureManager>

   <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
      httpPort="${httpPort}" httpsPort="${httpsPort}" />

   <application location="${project.build.finalName}.war" />

   <logging traceSpecification="${log.name}.*=${log.level}" />

</server>
```

microprofile-config.properties

```xml
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=airhacks
mp.jwt.verify.publickey=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgNSR7iZWlwOvJFyDFsva5XxUmRkBl3EjUn1OlV+jBj3LngKXBIujwAGCXYw+wr9JGJglmaOITqHtrow4j0T1wVGQF4cgN1o+FtcYyeDVsk+Ji3T3PaIIedgfzn1ufQUyWoeJAeROxmMOydImJeSe1o8VEP/ulvBAqq9IlJ2fw1Q521IE4geG5LywTSY/SdFo5zSs7sewNbZYKAguODEBQJNI85xe64mBwBKN2CKxVrwzq6plaVVBlityIcJLvh/pEXaBdnrEUXSfy4+Bf4jCIAUEV0O3GAR27fU5+tWdoHW0PIjjZ5W86D55JH+YWYOGQ06e+irLgHKxVNTIvpjE2QIDAQAB
```

Do I need to add a keystore? If so why would this be required?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, why configuration with `mp.jwt.verify.publickey` string doesn't work in OpenLiberty.

Anyway, I managed to make it working in this way:

microprofile-config.properties

```
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=airhacks
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=/META-INF/public-key.pem
```

public-key.pem

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIj... <public key>
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Got exactly the same problem and your solution worked. Thanks. Still weird.

Comment: @BramJanssens I'm glad that it helped you. You can upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is weird indeed. I just tested it with:

mp.jwt.verify.publickey=-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBIj... -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

and it works. I do not know why it wants header/footer declarations.

Comment: Here is the link to the current explanation why it does not work without headers -> https://github.com/OpenLiberty/guide-microprofile-jwt/issues/108